# CakePHP Test Controller add edit

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am testing controllers add method (CakePHP2.0).
But the issue is that what ever data I send as post gets added to my default databases and not my test database.
Heres the code.

```
public function testAdd() {
  $data = array(
  'Post' => array(
    'title' => 'Fourth Post Title',
    'body' => 'Fourth Post Body',
    'created' => '2012-01-22 21:31:52'
    )
  );
  $result = $this->testAction('/posts/add', array('data' => $data, 'method', 'post'));
  debug($result);
}
```

What I was actually expecting that the posted data togo into test DB that i configured in database.php and not in default DB.

Comment: As you set config/database.php DATABASE_CONFIG $default and $test?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few requirements for tests to occur in CakePHP 2.0 that you may want to double check:

Ensure that your Database Config setting in config/database.php is setup as

```
public $test = array(
  //Sample Test Settings Here
);
```

If you running tests from the web interface, debug must be set to at least 1 or else the tests will not run.

You can also validate that PHPUnit and your test database connection is working properly by running CakePHP core tests by navigating to: http://localhost/your_app/test.php and "AllConfigure" test.

All information from the CakePHP Book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, Actually my test cases run properly. The only issue is when testing controllers `add` request, the entries go into default DB. I have setup $test array as that in documentation. My test cases for model add request does not effect the default DB.